# Bash script doesn't exit SSH host after execution

Tags: bash, ssh, kvm

I am running a CentOS 7 VM that I want to set a static IP to.

Running `SSHPASS=password sshpass -e ssh -tt -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" host@192.168.122.229 'echo "password" | sudo -Sv && bash -s' < script.sh` executes all the commands in `script.sh` but, after completion, the terminal stays inside the VM, irregardless of whether I have the `exit` command at the end of my bash script or not.

The reason for piping my password is to skip entering it in the terminal.

Here is my bash script:

```
sudo cp /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens3  /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens3:0
sudo sed -i 's/BOOTPROTO="dhcp"/BOOTPROTO="static"/g' /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens3:0
sudo sed -i 's/NAME="ens3"/NAME="ens3:0"/g' /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens3:0
sudo sed -i 's/DEVICE="ens3"/DEVICE="ens3:0"/g' /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens3:0
echo 'PEERDNS="yes"' | sudo tee -a /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens3:0
echo 'IPADDR=192.168.122.201' | sudo tee -a /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens3:0
echo 'NETMASK=255.255.255.0' | sudo tee -a /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens3:0
echo 'GATEWAY=192.168.122.1' | sudo tee -a /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens3:0
sudo systemctl restart network
exit
```

Ideally, I would like to execute these commands in the same script but I can't seem to figure out what the problem is.

Interesting note: if I run `cat script.sh | SSHPASS=password sshpass -e ssh -tt host@192.168.122.229 'echo "password" | sudo -Sv && bash -s'` the console stops on the `exit` command (not inputted) and if I press enter to input it, the VM stalls and I can only exit with CTRL+C.

UPDATE
If I run `./script.sh` that has the following contents...

```
ssh -tt host@192.168.122.229 'echo "password" | sudo -Sv && bash -s' << EOF
echo
sudo cp /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens3  /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens3:0
sudo sed -i 's/BOOTPROTO="dhcp"/BOOTPROTO="static"/g' /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens3:0
sudo sed -i 's/NAME="ens3"/NAME="ens3:0"/g' /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens3:0
sudo sed -i 's/DEVICE="ens3"/DEVICE="ens3:0"/g' /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens3:0
echo 'PEERDNS="yes"' | sudo tee -a /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens3:0
echo 'IPADDR=192.168.122.201' | sudo tee -a /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens3:0
echo 'NETMASK=255.255.255.0' | sudo tee -a /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens3:0
echo 'GATEWAY=192.168.122.1' | sudo tee -a /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens3:0
exit
EOF
```

Everything works. Which leads me to believe that the problem is related to `sudo systemctl restart network`. Confirmed by adding `sudo systemctl restart network; exit` at the end of the script. Maybe it has something to do with the nature of this command.

Comment: Did you try it without `-tt`?

Comment: I get the ```sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified``` error addressed in another StackOverflow question.

Comment: There is no point in making a copy of a file, then using `sed -i` on it. Just use  `sed` on the original (your three separate calls can be collapsed into one) and write the output to a new file.

Comment: @chepner I want two interfaces

Comment: And you can do that. You just don't need the nonstandard `-i` option to `sed` to accomplish it.

Answer (score 1):

Your goal is to edit a file in your VM. Neither of your commands runs anything except `echo "password"` on the VM.

### What (should) work

The following isn't tested. What you *want* is to have `sudo` run *remotely*, reading from the script that `ssh` passes across the connection via standard input. Something like

```
SSHPASS=password sshpass -e ssh host@192.168.122.229 \
  '{ echo "password"; cat; }| sudo -Sv bash' < script.sh
```

The `cat` ensures that everything `ssh` sends over the connection is read by `sudo` *after* it reads the password from standard input.

---

### What was wrong

Your first command

```
SSHPASS=password sshpass -e ssh \
                         -tt \
                         -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" \
                         host@192.168.122.229 'echo "password" |
  sudo -Sv &&
bash -s' < script.sh
```

starts by running `sshpass`. It logs into the remote host, runs `echo "password"`, then logs out. That output is piped to `sudo -Sv`, which, having no command to run, just ignores its input and exits successfully. Then `bash` runs the code read from your script locally.

Your second command,

```
cat script.sh | 
  SSHPASS=password sshpass -e ssh -tt host@192.168.122.229 'echo "password" |
  sudo -Sv &&
bash -s'
```

pipes the contents of your script to `sshpass`, which again logs into the remote host and executes the command, ignoring your script, and exiting. `sudo` then ignores its input and exits successfully, starting `bash -s` which blocks, waiting for input.

---

Incidentally, your script can be simplified to

```
cd /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts
{
  sed -e 's/BOOTPROTO="dhcp"/BOOTPROTO="static"/g' \
      -e 's/NAME="ens3"/NAME="ens3:0"/g' \
      -e 's/DEVICE="ens3"/DEVICE="ens3:0"/g' ifcfg-ens3
  echo 'PEERDNS="yes"'
  echo 'IPADDR=192.168.122.201'
  echo 'NETMASK=255.255.255.0'
  echo 'GATEWAY=192.168.122.1'
} > ifcfg-ens3:0
systemctl restart network
```

No `sudo` (because the script is executed *with* `sudo`), and one `sed` command (reading from the original file)  and multiple `echo` all writing to the same output file.

Comment: I tried multiple variations of your response, it doesn't work. However much I would like to say I understand it, I still don't.

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like this

```
ssh -t ubuntu@xyz.com << EOF
 command1
 command2
 exit
EOF
```

**OR**

```
SSHPASS=password sshpass -e ssh -tt -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" host@192.168.122.229 'echo "password" | sudo -Sv && bash -s' < script.sh && exit
```

Comment: Doesn't work, not even with the ```-tt``` option. It also doesn't work if I specify ```ssh -t me@server1.com /bin/bash << EOF etc.```

Comment: @LarsonKeys I have updated my answer with other approach too could you please try with that.

Comment: Again, it stops inside the VM on the last command (```sudo systemctl restart network```) with or without ```exit``` in the script or in the command you mentioned.

Comment: Can you just run without your this command ```sudo systemctl restart network``` just to make sure ```exit``` is worked or not.

Comment: ```sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart ``` please try with this instead of  ```sudo systemctl restart network``` and run script with my 2nd approach.

Comment: Not a valid command. I think it's interesting to note that even if I type ```exit``` manually while in the VM, the machine just stalls.

Comment: I basically run like this
```which bash > script.sh```
```sudo nano script.sh```
```sudo chmod +x script.sh```
```yes | ./script.sh```